# How to plot a 95% confidence interval graph for one sample proportion

Tags: r, ggplot2, sample, confidence-interval

[image]

```
qplot(x="SignUp", y=0.07, ymin=Lower_Level, ymax=Upper_Level, ylim=c(0,1), geom = "pointrange")+coord_flip() +
  
  ylab("SignUp Proportion")+geom_hline(yintercept=Upper_Level)+geom_hline(yintercept=Lower_Level)
```

This is what I managed to plot. But I want something like the graph below. The confidence intervals are 0.084 and 0.0551. The sample proportion is 0.07

[image]

Comment: The bottom graph is not a confidence interval. The top graph kind of is a confidence interval but a confidence interval only has one axis:  high, low, estimate all on the same axis. Are you trying to do a bootstrap CI?

Comment: @Elin I'm not very sure about the bootstrap CI. But I think that's what I need.

Comment: Is this homework? You should look at the context and figure out what is being requested, bcase as I said, the first graph is definitely showing a regular frequentist confidence interval.  The graph you are showing basically -- without knowing the context I'm inferring this-- is showing probably what happens if you bootstrap your sample.   Do you have the actual sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could show the 95% confidence interval for the estimated probability like this:

First, start with a data frame of 1s and 0s representing your "success" and "failure" rate in the sample. Here, your numbers suggest approximately 105 out of 1500 successes, so we do:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(1, 105), rep(0, 1395)))
```

Now we fit a logistic regression with the intercept being the only parameter we are estimating:

```r
mod <- coef(summary(glm(x ~ 1, family = binomial, data = df)))

mod
#>              Estimate Std. Error  z value      Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept) -2.586689  0.1011959 -25.5612 4.122466e-144
```

The estimate here should be normally distributed (on the log odds scale) with the given estimate and standard error, so we can grab the density values over an appropriate range by doing:

```r
xvals <- seq(mod[1] - 3 * mod[2], mod[1] + 3 * mod[2], 0.01)
yvals <- dnorm(xvals, mod[1], mod[2])
```

Now we convert the x values from log odds to probabilities:

```r
pxvals <- exp(xvals)/(1 + exp(xvals))
```

We will also create a vector that labels whether the values are within 1.96 standard deviations of the estimate:

```r
level <- ifelse(xvals < mod[1] - 1.96 * mod[2], "lower",
          ifelse(xvals > mod[1] + 1.96 * mod[2], "upper", "estimate"))
```

Now we put all of these in a data frame and plot:

```r
plot_df <- data.frame(xvals, yvals, pxvals, level)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot_df, aes(pxvals, yvals, fill = level)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = exp(mod[1])/(1 + exp(mod[1])), linetype = 2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray70", "deepskyblue4", "deepskyblue4"),
                    guide = guide_none()) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.03, 0.13), breaks = 3:12/100,
                     name = "probability") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that because we have transformed the x axis, this is no longer a genuine density plot. The y axis becomes somewhat arbitrary as a result, but the plot still shows accurately the 95% confidence interval for the probability estimate.

---

**EDIT**

Here's an alternative method if the `glm` approach seems too complicated. It uses the binomial distribution to get the 95% confidence intervals. You just supply it with the population size and the number of "successes"

```
library(ggplot2)

population <- 1500
actual_successes <- 105
test_successes <- 1:300

density <- dbinom(test_successes, population, actual_successes/population)
probs   <- pbinom(test_successes, population, actual_successes/population)
label   <- ifelse(probs < 0.025, "low", ifelse(probs > 0.975, "high", "CI"))

ggplot(data.frame(probability = test_successes/population, density, label),
       aes(probability, density, fill = label)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = actual_successes/population, linetype = 2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray70", "deepskyblue4", "deepskyblue4"),
                    guide = guide_none()) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.03, 0.13), breaks = 3:12/100,
                     name = "probability") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to plot something similar without using the logistic regression model.?

Comment: @JohnPaul possibly - why, what's the problem with it?

Comment: I actually want a simple plot to depict the confidence interval of the population. This looks fine, but a little too complex for me. Would be a great help if I can plot a similar one without having to do the regression.

Comment: @JohnPaul I have included a simpler version which should give the same result. It's not really possible to do this much more simply, unless someone has put similar code in a package already. I'm not aware of one though.